# How to pass Grails test with Geb and Spock? (using grails-functional-test-development)

Tags: grails, spock, geb

Please help.

I have page login/auth.gsp

with the following code inside the body

```
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div class="login-block">
    <g:if test="${flash.message}">
      <h3  class='login_message'>${flash.message}</h3>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
      <h3>IMMS Login</h3>
    </g:else>
    <form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='cssform' autocomplete='off'>
      <p>
        <label for='username'><g:message code="auth.username.label" default="User Name"/></label>
        <input type='text' class='text_' name='j_username' id='username'/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for='password'><g:message code="auth.password.label" default="Password"/></label>
        <input type='password' class='text_' name='j_password' id='password'/>
      </p>
      <p class="submit-wrap">
        <input type='submit' value="${message(code: 'default.button.Login.label', default: 'Login')}"/>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="image-block"></div>
</div>
```

Under test/functional/pages dir, I have LoginPage

```
package pages

import geb.Page

class LoginPage extends Page {
  static url = "login/auth/"
  static at = {
    userName.text() == ""
  }
  static content = {
    userName { $("input", name : "j_username") }
    password { $("input", name : "j_password") }
    loginButton(to: IndexPage){ $(".submit-wrap").find("input").first() }
  }
}
```

And here is my testing code

```
import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import pages.*
import spock.lang.Stepwise
@Stepwise
class BaseSpec extends GebReportingSpec {
  String getBaseUrl() {
    return "http://localhost:8080/IMMS/"
  }

  def "open URL"() {
    when:
    to LoginPage
    then:
    at LoginPage
  }

}
```

I run the test and failed. This is the report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="1" hostname="SGCDMSSVR" name="BaseSpec" tests="1" time="24.715" timestamp="2011-07-12T07:00:04">
  <properties />
  <testcase classname="BaseSpec" name="open URL" time="24.693">
    <failure message="Condition not satisfied:

at LoginPage
|
false
" type="junit.framework.AssertionFailedError">junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Condition not satisfied:

at LoginPage
|
false

    at BaseSpec.open URL(BaseSpec.groovy:18)
</failure>
  </testcase>
  <system-out><![CDATA[--Output from open URL--
]]></system-out>
  <system-err><![CDATA[--Output from open URL--
]]></system-err>
</testsuite>
```

Any idea to help me? am I missing some configuration or my jQuery-like navigation is incorrect?

For the testing, I'm using "Functional Test Development" plugin.

---

Update:
Initially I used GebConfig exactly from [The sample.](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails)
I just noticed that the default driver is HTMLUnit.

When I run the functional test using [Functional Test Development](https://github.com/alkemist/grails-functional-test-development) feature from command console.

```
grails develop-functional-tests
```

I select option to run all functional test. The console shown failed tests.

When I change the default driver to Firefox.
It still failed but I can see it automatically open Firefox browser and open the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/IMMS/login/auth.gsp
```

and it failed to open the URL 404. I think this is the reason why the test failed.

I tried to run the following from IDE.

```
grails test-app -functional
```

It works and firefox browser opened and it did what's written test script and the test pass.

So, I revise the title here. The focus now is on the grails' functional test dev plugin.
Perhaps any of you ever tried this plugin and has answer?
Thanks.

PS: Am I allow to revise the question? or should I create new question in stackoverflow?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but maybe try removing the trailing slash in the `url` property of your `LoginPage` (`login/auth` instead of `login/auth/`). I don't see why would Geb add the `.gsp` at the end otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the creator of the grails plugin [here](https://github.com/alkemist/grails-functional-test-development/issues/2). 
So basically, it's not about the test code problem. I just need to use different port for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Your `at` condition for the `LoginPage` is failing (either you're not in the page you expect, or there is some problem in your markup that makes the condition fail). You'll get more information by putting an `assert` inside it.

Like:

```
package pages

import geb.Page

class LoginPage extends Page {
  static url = "login/auth/"
  static at = {
    assert userName.text() == ""
    true
  }
  static content = {
    userName { $("input", name : "j_username") }
    password { $("input", name : "j_password") }
    loginButton(to: IndexPage){ $(".submit-wrap").find("input").first() }
  }
}
```

That should tell you what's the actual value of your selector.

In any case, I think that condition is brittle. For page identification you're better of checking the title of the document, or some specific string, such as a page header. In your case, I'd match the `<h3>` header. I.e.:

```
static at = {
  assert $('h3').text() =~ /IMMS Login/
  true
}
```

(That `true` at the end is so the at-checking doesn't fail, since you're already asserting the condition, but the assert has `null` value.).

Also, check [this](http://ldaley.com/post/1013531080/painless-page-identification-with-geb-grails) blog post for a more consistent alternative.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think it's more on the plugin that I use to run. I'll try to put assert and see

Comment: In that respect, it is fine indeed. Adding the `assert` will allow you "fail early" and get more information about why the at condition is failing, that's all. See here for a more thorough discussion on at checking: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#at_checking and http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/pages.html#at_verification . I had to add the `true` at the end though, otherwise my at conditions would always fail when using `assert`.

Comment: The second link recommends using `assert` just to get the benefit of its detailed output.

Comment: yes, sorry, I got it wrongly in my first read. Btw, I've update the question with new finding. Thanks.